# Angular 7 - Can't bind to @Input() property

Tags: angular, binding

Using Angular 7.2.0, I have the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer} from "../../services/customers.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent {
  @Input() customer: Customer;
}
```

In a parent template, I have:

```
 <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" *ngFor="let c of customers">
   <summary [customer]="c"></summary>
</div>
```

Trying to compile it raises the following exception:

```
ERROR in : Can't bind to 'customer' since it isn't a known property 
  of'summary'. ("
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" *ngFor="let c of customers">
    <summary [ERROR ->][customer]="c"></summary>
  </div>
")
```

I can't figure out what may happen here as the mentioned property is defined in the component. Could any one please help ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: it should be `<app-summary ....` instead of `<summary ...`

Comment: This was it, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is: `'app-summary'`.

Use `<app-summary [customer]="c"></app-summary>`

Answer (score -1):

You should bind `<app-summary [customer]="">` like wise, you are binding to `<summary>` which is HTML tag and not an angular component.